# Scraping font colour from webpage into excel

Tags: html, parsing, fonts, colors, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape website data and there are different font colors in the text I'm extracting - most of the font is in black but when it's green it indicates a win and when it's red it indicates a loss. I'm trying to get the different font colors to show up on the excel sheet as they show on the site. Currently I've been using $e.outerHTML.contains("green") black red and so on in the hopes it will then display the text data in the colors in excel but all it does is show the HTML tags next to the data. What is the best way to go about this? Is it even possible to do this or will I just have to edit the HTML tags via VBA once I've got the raw data?

Tried outer HTML tags with the colors listed which have not worked. See below for example:

$e.outerHTML.contains("green")

Trying to get the excel file to show the data in the colors as it does on the site.

Comment: Could you show us a snippet of the HTML you are trying to scrape and the javascript you are using?

Comment: you may be able to do whole thing with vba. Would help to share the url /html.